# Radio buttons need to click twice to reflect change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1.whenever i click on radio button it call the handleOptionChange callback but not reflect the change in html.
2.but when i click twice on radio button it reflect the change

> My question is why i need to click twice on radio buttons? Is am i doing anything wrong?

```
class CompleteProfile extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            teacher_role:'subject'
        };
        this.handleOptionChange = this.handleOptionChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleOptionChange(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        let { name, value } = event.target;
        this.setState( { [name]:value } );
    }

    render(){
        let { teacher_role } = this.state;
        console.log('teacher:',teacher_role);
        return(
            <Wrapper className="complete-profile">
                <CustomContainer>
                    <Title>complete profile</Title>
                    <ProfileCard>
                        <Form noValidate>

                            <FormGroup>
                                <label>I want to enroll as:</label>

                                <label htmlFor="test">
                                    <input id="test" type="radio" name="teacher_role" value="subject" checked={ teacher_role === 'subject' } onChange={ this.handleOptionChange } />
                                    subject teacher
                                </label>

                                <label htmlFor="test1">
                                    <input id="test1" type="radio" name="teacher_role" value="chapter" checked={ teacher_role === 'chapter' } onChange={ this.handleOptionChange } />
                                    class teacher
                                </label>

                                <label htmlFor="test2">
                                    <input id="test2" type="radio" name="teacher_role" value="both" checked={ teacher_role === 'both' } onChange={ this.handleOptionChange } />
                                    both
                                </label>

                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </ProfileCard>
                </CustomContainer>
            </Wrapper>
        )
    }

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps){

    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){

    }

}
```

Comment: maybe you can set up a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with your example to visualize the problem better?

Comment: here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6x9wolml4n) of above problem

Comment: @PrakashNaidu Does it work if you use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`?

Comment: got a solution **e.preventDefault()** inside the **handleOptionChange** function is the reason.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

remove `event.preventDefault();` from your `handleOptionChange` method

Answer (score 23):

For others running into this problem, make sure you are not using the same `name` property for multiple groups of radio buttons.

This can happen when mapping through an array and rendering a set of radio buttons for each array item. Avoid this issue by adding the index of the current array item to the radio button name.

Note that in this case there should be no need for `preventDefault` in the `handleOptionChange` method.

Comment: Missing rendering a `<form>` tag wrapping the radio buttons was my culprit. Effectively placing me in the multiple groups with same `name` property scenario.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks a ton this saved me.
@Neill : Name attribute makes sure you cant select multiple radio button with same name attribute

Comment: I had multiple groups that where only one was displayed using ng-if and I still had to give them different names

Answer (score 13):

If you are using React also be careful about your `checked` tag property in your radio inputs. For me a badly set checked attribute when I wanted a defaultly checked radio button caused this problem.

See [this](https://thewebdev.info/2020/04/30/set-the-default-checked-value-of-a-react-radio-button/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20a%20radio%20button,will%20check%20the%20right%20one.) for a possible fix.

UPDATE: use `defaultChecked` instead of `checked`, that fixed it

Comment: defaultChecked works for react. The best clean solution here, this should be the top answer

Comment: This works with Formik as well.  Was having the same double click issue, defaultChecked instead of checked solved it

Comment: defaultChecked workd solved my problem also

Answer (score 8):

If you are like me and need to use `event.preventDefault()`, for example to prevent the input from submitting. You can use `event.stopPropagation()` instead.

see [this issue comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3446#issuecomment-82751540) explaining for more context

Comment: I am using materialize css radio buttons in react event.stopPropagation() solved double click problem in my case thanks.

Comment: Had the same issue due to using `preventDefault` on my `form` element. Changing to `stopPropagation` fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem can occur if the `input` and `label` elements in your DOM are overlapping. What worked for me was just inspecting the DOM carefully and removing overlap between these two.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and solved this problem by adding the checked state to the key of the component.
Something like this:

```
<Radio key={ radioKey + isChecked }/>
```

The component will rerender every time the checked state will change

Answer (score 0):

It can also happen, if you are using a condition for checking the previous state and current state of form, and the previous state has not changed. This was the case with me.

Check your updater function (for people coming here for solution).

1. See that you provide a second callback to `setState` or use `useEffect` if using hooks in this case.
2. You are using same keys or IDs on two different DOM elements.
3. Use of `e.preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I have a similar problem. Using useEffect cause me the following problem:
When I click on submit without providing a value, an error message appears. Then when I select any of the radio buttons it removes the error message but I have to click a second time to set the value. When I console.log() it, I can see that the value is selected on the first click but is showing on the second one..

```
 useEffect(() => {
   setError(props.error ? true : false);
   setValue(props.value ? props.value : '');
   setErrorMessage(props.errorMessage ? props.errorMessage : '');
 }, [props.value1, props.value2, props.value, props.error, props.errorMessage]);
```

When I pass an empty array at the end of the useEffect(), submitting without a selected value won't trigger the error message but selecting a value will work with one click only.. Any suggestions?